# How do we escape the android and ios envoirment when creating mobile apps?

Tags: android, ios

I want to build a mobile app that works on all phones,cross platform .

Here is my problem :
ios wants to charge me $99 per year and android wants a $25 fee

I find it very unfair ... as it will be a free app without ads.

Question 1
Is it possible to create apk's for ios also ?

Question 2
What tool should i use to build my mobile app so it works on all?(android,ios,windows,linux etc)

Is there anything better then electron ?

Comment: You can evaluate Flutter or ReactNative. But both require a macOS device for building the ios app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a framework called Ionic. It lets you design applications for both android, and ios. You can read more about it from this link:
https://ionicframework.com/what-is-ionic

Comment: nope not good ... we need something so users can download something like .apk for iOS also ...so we don't pay the apple store fee

Comment: it won't be possible without having an iOS developer account. Sorry